# looking for a technique for conducting experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, vibrations, sensor

I have used a servomotor and a controlling circuit to produce oscillatory motion for an experiment that involves flapping of a tiny metal plate (~few mm) inside liquid. I could not be very successful in controlling the amplitude and the frequency precisely. 
Is there any technique or method like magnetic or electric piezo crystals or robotic technology I can use to produce intended motion?

Comment: Frequency and timing control are trivial if you use the right instruments (digital waveform generator or timing source) and as for the actuator... no need to reinvent the wheel, either. Search for "industrial actuator" and you will find plenty of suitable products.

Comment: What was the reason you did not succeed in controlling amplitude and frequency?  What liquid did you use?  What frequency range?

Comment: I was studying reciprocal motion with frequency range 1-10 hz and amplitude around 6 mm.

Comment: Sounds like the problem was not accuracy of control.  Possibly the motor was not able to provide enough torque to move the plate through the liquid at those frequencies and amplitudes, because of inertial and viscous forces.  You may need a more powerful motor.

Comment: I suggest you flag the question for Moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated to Engineering SE.  Probably you also need to give more details of your experimental setup, and what exactly was the problem you were having.

Answer (score 0):

I would reach for an [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Servo) or similar microcontroller to do the job.  You can set the amplitude and frequency of the vibration in code which, in my experience, is always easier than tweaking an electronic circuit.

Comment: I can write a very precise frequency source in programmable logic for you in minutes, much faster than most people can do it with a microcontroller. Not that one needs to reinvent the wheel, anyway, there are plenty of test and measurement instruments out there for that purpose.

Comment: thanks for your help. could u please let me know what hardware n software required to be bought?

Comment: If you've got a servomotor all you should need is an Arduino and a USB cable .  You can power it with a USB cable or a 9V battery or other DC source.  The Arduino is widely available for about $30.(https://www.pololu.com/product/2191) (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno).  Software needed to program it is freely downloadable (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software).